# In Jasmine Test string __proto__ doesn't equal String.prototype

Tags: javascript, jasmine

If I have the test like so, which should pass
`expect("test".__proto__ === String.prototype).toBe(true)`
it fails with the error `Expected false to be true.`

The reason I'm testing this is because in my code jquery extensions adds format to String.prototype. However, when I go todo my test
`"my test {0}".format(1)` I get "undefined is not a function", and looking closer all string in a Jasmine test dont have the String.prototype as their prototype.

---EDIT---
After further testing I found that if I have:

```
it("test string prototype", function() {
   var test_string = "test"
   expect(test_string.__proto__ === String.prototype).toBe(true)
   with (frameContext) {
      expect(test_string.__proto__ === String.prototype).toBe(true)
   }
});
```

the first expect passes but the second doesn't.

---EDIT---

```
expect(typeof String.prototype.format !== "undefined").toBe(true)
expect(test_string.__proto__ === String.prototype).toBe(true)
with (frameContext) {
    expect(typeof String.prototype.format !== "undefined").toBe(true)
    expect(test_string.__proto__ === String.prototype).toBe(true)
}
```

first expect fails, second expect passes

within the with, first expect pass, and second fails.

Comment: It's a strange test. What are you checking with it?

Comment: Passes when I run it with Jasmine 2

Comment: Maybe this should be added to the answer for [Why is extending native objects bad practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034180/why-is-extending-native-objects-a-bad-practice) :)

Comment: don't use "with", see warning here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with

Comment: What is `frameContext`, and what do you expect `with` to do about it?